# set visibility on textBox from form1 to form2

Tags: c#, compact-framework

From other Form i want to set visibility for textBoxes on this form but i down't know how to call TextBoxes and set property Visible = false.

I try with Enums but i still can't solve problem. I can not cast or do anything. So how can i call textBox From form1 to form2...

i am using C# and CF 3.5

```
public enum VnosTextBoxType
    {
        Ean, PredmetObravnave, Tse, Kolicina, EnotaMere, 
        Lokacija, Zapora, Sarza, SarzaDobavitelja, Datumod, 
        DatumDo 
    }
```

this are names for all my TextBoxes. I have TextBoxes with names like txtEan, txtPredmetObravnave,..

Comment: How exactly were you planning to use an enum to solve this problem ?

Comment: So this.textBox1.Visibe = other.textBox1.Visible; doesn't do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about writing on Form2 a method like this:

```
public void SetTBVisible(string name, bool visible)
{
    this.Controls[name].Visible = visible;
}
```

and call this form your Form1?

**EDITED:**

```
public void SetTBVisible(string name, bool visible)
{
    string cName = name.ToLower();
    foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
        if (c.Name.ToLower() == cName)
        {
            c.Visible = visible;
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Controls acept only int. string is not assignable to type int

Comment: @V4Vendetta: in normal framework it has, yes. I cannot test on CF right now, but I thought that was not different. I suppose it was :(

Comment: same here, maybe he could use `Find` least that should be available

Comment: thx boath for help. Looks like it works. Thx again. CF is completely different then .NEt 3.5. I can not even use FindComponent :((

Answer (score 1):

Make a new class called Globals.cs
write:

```
    public static Form1 MainForm;
    public static Form2 ChildForm;
```

go to Form1 and make the event: form load
put:

```
Globals.MainWindow = this;
```

and:

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

and do the same in Form2 with ChildForm
now you can call form2 with: Globals.ChildForm.TextBox1.Visible = false;

Edit: don't forget to make your textBox public.

Answer (score 1):

let say you want to set Visible = false for textbox1 of form1

when you create instance of form2 then you have pass the instance of form1 into its constructor like this

```
Class Form1 : Form 
{
    public void setTextbox(bool val)
    {
       this.Textbox1.visible=val;
    }
    Public void showForm2()
    {
       Form2 f2= new Form2(this);
       f2.show();
    }        
}

Class Form2 : Form 
{
    Form1 f1;

    public Form2(Form form1)
    {
        f1=form1;
    }

    public void setTb()
    {
    f1.setTextbox(false);
    }

}
```

I Hope this will help you